# Why does .textContent add unexpected content to the document body

Tags: javascript, html

I was recently playing around and noticed some strange behaviour involving the `.textContent` property.

```js
// I understand that .innerHTML should be used here.
document.body.textContent += 'string<br />';
document.body.textContent += 'string<br />';
```

My question is not how to prevent this from happening, the question is: What is causing the code to be added to the document body, why is this happening only for the first `.textContent` and not the second?

Also note that `string<br />` is being added to the body.

Other curiosities: This behaviour is reproducible in firefox and chrome, both in code snippits and normal web pages but not in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/jgy79h97/)

Comment: It repro's in the fiddle if you put the `<script>` tag in the right place.  http://jsfiddle.net/jgy79h97/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is placed in the body by the stack snippet.

That `script` element contains some text content (the code of your script), which is hidden.

However, `textContent` includes it anyway. If you used the non-standard IE's `innerText`, that wouldn't happen.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent),

> [**Differences from innerText**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)
>
> Internet Explorer introduced `element.innerText`. The intention is
>   similar but with the following differences:
>
> - While `textContent` gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements, the IE-specific property `innerText` does
>     not.
> - `innerText` is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas `textContent` will.
> - As `innerText` is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas `textContent` will not.

Comment: Fair. I actually figured it out like 3 seconds after I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Because the code is in the document body.

```
<body>
    <script></script>
</body>
```

It is in the head in the fiddle.

```
<html>
    <script></script>
</html>
<body>
</body>
```

The textContent is selecting all of the text of the body and the sibling  elements and you are adding to it.